# Datetimezone Error for website

Tags: php, apache, datetime, timezone

When I try to enter the site a white page appears

```
[Mon May 21 21:06:21.190385 2018] [:error] [pid 13340] [client 89.64.24.10:19041] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$default_timezone in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 92
[Mon May 21 21:06:21.193439 2018] [:error] [pid 13340] [client 89.64.24.10:19041] PHP Notice:  date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID '' is invalid in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 92
[Mon May 21 21:06:21.193476 2018] [:error] [pid 13340] [client 89.64.24.10:19041] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$default_timezone in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 93
[Mon May 21 21:06:21.193603 2018] [:error] [pid 13340] [client 89.64.24.10:19041] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone () in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php:93\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php(93): DateTimeZone->__construct('')\n#1 /var/www/html/frontend/htdocs/index.php(4): include('/var/www/html/f...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 93
```

time zone line 92-93-94-95 (common.php)

```
date_default_timezone_set($CFG->default_timezone);
$dtz = new DateTimeZone($CFG->default_timezone);
$dtz1 = new DateTime('now', $dtz);
$CFG->timezone_offset = $dtz->getOffset($dtz1);
```

Comment: "Uncaught Exception: DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone" theats the issue. how about running `var_dump($CFG->default_timezone)` to see the value used

Comment: I checked now but still not  working. @smith

Comment: what was the result?

Comment: unexpected '$dtz1' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 94
 @smith

Comment: well thats the problem then. its not set, hence the fatal error

Comment: what should I do ? @smith

Comment: set a valid timezone? fins where `$CFG->default_timezone` is created? you dont seem to be even trying here

Comment: I checked everything ,files are look good but I don't know what's wrong with files. @smith